# Obfuscated source-code in Qt Community Edition. Still comply the license?

Tags: qt5, licensing

One customer was not properly adviced by a former freelancer and used Community License of Qt5. (LGPL)
Now they are close to release, and found out, that they should open the source-code. They would like ty bye the license, not the question of money, but the license model of Qt doesn't allow to switch from Community to Commercial.

So my question is: Is it allowed to obfuscate at least some parts of code, and still use Community Edition?

P.S.: I know it's not fair. I have a valid license myself.

Comment: The question has little to do with Qt. What LGPL version exactly? And why do you think you need to release your application's source code?

Comment: Besides: no, it's not allowed to obfuscate parts of the code. Quoting: *"Source code" for a work means the preferred form of the work for making modifications to it*

Comment: Last: "but the license model of Qt doesn't allow to switch from Community to Commercial." is not true.

Comment: @peppe: My License knowledge is from 4.8 ages. Could you give the references for your last 2 comments? If you put them all as answer, they would answer my question.

Comment: Well the quote comes straight from the LGPL v2.1 license: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.en.html

Comment: For the LGPL->Commercial upgrade: contact The Qt Company, explain your situation and ask for a quote. See also: https://www.qt.io/faq/ "
If I have started development of a project using the open source version (LGPL), can I later purchase a commercial version of Qt and move my code under that license?
This is not permitted without written consent from The Qt Company. If you have already started the development with an open-source version of Qt, please contact The Qt Company to resolve the issue."

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in LGPL license you can publish binary without source code. But there are some exception, like that if you changed Qt's source code (or any other [L]GPL source code that you modified it) you must publish the changes. And your application MUST NOT be depend on a open-source (e.g. GPL) library.

Comment: Concerning the obfuscation the answer is NO as peppe already wrote in comments. Concerning "changed Qt's source" you are also not well informed. Including  qstring alone means integration of LGPL code into your closed-source code. Unfortunatelly the same wrong misunderstanding of LGPL made my customer running into the trouble.